# JSON Serialisation - How to flatten nested object structures using JSON.net/Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following JSON structure :

```
{
       "Name":"",
       "Children":[
          {
             "ID":"1",
             "MetaData":[
                {
                   "Info":{
                      "GUID":"cdee360d-7ea9-477d-994f-12f492b9e1ed"
                   },
                   "Data":{
                      "Text":"8"
                   },
                   "Name":"DataId"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

and I want to flatten the MetaData and nested Info and Data objects in the array. I also want to use the Name field as a field name for Text value so it becomes "DataId" : "8".

```
  {
       "Name":"",
       "Children":[
          {
             "ID":"1",
             "GUID":"cdee360d-7ea9-477d-994f-12f492b9e1ed",
             "DataId":"8"
          }
       ]
    }
```

So far I've used a Contract Resolver to get me so far:

```
private class DynamicContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
        {
            private readonly List<string> _propertiesToSerialize;
            private readonly List<string> _itemTypeNames;

            public DynamicContractResolver(List<string> propertiesToSerialize, List<string> itemTypeNames)
            {
                _propertiesToSerialize = propertiesToSerialize;

                _itemTypeNames = itemTypeNames;
            }

            protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
            {
                var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

                    properties = properties.Where(p => _propertiesToSerialize.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
                }

                return properties;
            }
}
```

How do I go about getting my desired serialisation?

Comment: Can you show the C# classes you're serializing? Also is the `MetaData` array always guaranteed to just have one element?

Comment: Without posting all the code, the classes are basically a tree structure in the same structure as the first sample JSON. MetaData could have many elements. I've found an acceptable solution by creating alias type properties to some of the nested structures to flatten them. I would have preferred to not involve the underlying classes in this but at least it's merely extra properties and little to no logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your types at all, you can use [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to load and preprocess your JSON, like so:

```
        // Load the JSON into an intermediate JObject
        var rootObj = JObject.Parse(json);

        // Restructure the JObject hierarchy
        foreach (var obj in rootObj.SelectTokens("Children[*]").OfType<JObject>())
        {
            var metadata = obj.SelectToken("MetaData[0]"); // Get the first entry in the "MetaData" array.
            if (metadata != null)
            {
                // Remove the entire "Metadata" property.
                metadata.Parent.RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent();
                // Set the name and value
                var name = metadata.SelectToken("Name");
                var id = metadata.SelectToken("Data.Text");
                if (name != null && id != null)
                    obj[(string)name] = (string)id;
                // Move all other atomic values.
                foreach (var value in metadata.SelectTokens("..*").OfType<JValue>().Where(v => v != id && v != name).ToList())
                    value.MoveTo(obj);
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(rootObj);

        // Now deserialize the preprocessed JObject to the final class
        var root = rootObj.ToObject<RootObject>();
```

Using a couple of simple extension methods for convenience:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveFromLowestPossibleParent(this JToken node)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var contained = node.AncestorsAndSelf().Where(t => t.Parent is JArray || t.Parent is JObject).FirstOrDefault();
        if (contained != null)
            contained.Remove();
    }

    public static void MoveTo(this JToken token, JObject newParent)
    {
        if (newParent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var toMove = token.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<JProperty>().First(); // Throws an exception if no parent property found.
        toMove.Remove();
        newParent.Add(toMove);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't find the SelectTokens() in the JObject

Comment: @sarath_rachuri - it's on the base class, `JToken.SelectTokens(String)`.  See the docs here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm.  It was added in [Json.NET 6.0 Release 1](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support) in Feb 2014, so make sure you are not using an older version.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I was using an old version of newtonsoft.